# Occasional Duplicate Entry when max+1 method used in php / mysql

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

My code below. rnum is Receipt No. I get max receipt no. and make +1 to that number as new receipt no. for new record. But when multiple users are working, occasional duplicate entries found in mysql db. I am using redbeanphp for accessing database. we found 1 duplicate entry on an average of 800 records.

```
$rnum = 1;

$receipt = R::findOne('receipts', '1 ORDER BY rnum DESC');  

if (isset($rcprec->id)) {
    $rnum = $receipt->rnum + 1;
}

$rcptmain = R::dispense( 'receipts' );

$rcptmain->rdate = $dor;
$rcptmain->srdate = $sdor;
$rcptmain->studid = $sid;
$rcptmain->course = $course;
$rcptmain->part = $part;
$rcptmain->otherfees = $otherfees;
$rcptmain->rnum = $rnum;

$id = R::store( $rcptmain );
```

Comment: I guess making the `rnum` to be autoincrement is not a variant?

Answer (score 1):

Modify table to enforce it in the db with an autoincrement column

Such as
Create table Invoice
 ( invID int unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT primary key

...
)

or the like. Dont cache a max in code the way u are

---

Another way, have a single table containing nextnums for several main real tables. Lets call this NextNum.
It has two colunms, tblnm and nextid
Entries are like

'invoice',888517

'customer',5617

The code calls a stored proc/procedure to get a next num passing a param of tbl such as 'invoice'

Proc does a read lock. get. update with plus1. release lock.

Invoice can of course be saved as string '20150529-88517' in invoice tbl

It is a nearly instantaneous and completely save concurrency approach